# convert struct of bitfields to binary format

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-fields

[R Instruction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7FfO.png) [J Instruction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SrOk.png) [J Instruction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiEuA.png) [Instruction Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mgHf.png)

So, I'm trying to convert 32bit instructions to machine-code binary.

Instruction for example: `add #3, #5, #9`:

- has an opcode of **0**.
- `rs` will have the first operand value (**3**),  `rt` will have the 2nd value (**5**) and `rd` will have the 3rd (**9**).
- funct **1**
- 6 bits of unused value, just **0s**
- `#x - represent a register in memory`

therefore the above R-type instruction will be represented in binary like so:

> `opCode` `rs` `rt` `rd` `funct` `unused`

> `000001 00011 00101 01001 00001 000000` - **32 bits/4B** instruction

---

My attempt to store each instruction:

```
typedef union __attribute__((__packed__))
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned opcode : 6;
        unsigned rs : 5;
        unsigned rt : 5;
        unsigned rd : 5;
        unsigned funct : 5;
        unsigned unused : 6;
    } r;
    struct
    {
        unsigned first : 8;
        unsigned second : 8;
        unsigned third : 8;
        unsigned fourth : 8;
    } bytes;
} r_instruction;

typedef union __attribute__((__packed__))
{

    struct
    {

        unsigned rs : 5;
        unsigned rt : 5;
        unsigned opcode : 6;
        unsigned immed : 16;
    } i;
    struct
    {
        unsigned first : 8;
        unsigned second : 8;
        unsigned third : 8;
        unsigned fourth : 8;
    } bytes;
} i_instruction;

typedef union __attribute__((__packed__))
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned addr : 25;
        unsigned opcode : 6;
        unsigned isReg : 1;
    } j;
    struct
    {
        unsigned first : 8;
        unsigned second : 8;
        unsigned third : 8;
        unsigned fourth : 8;
    } bytes;
} j_instruction;
```

I need to output each instruction binary (like in the example) to a file, where each line is the instruction described in 4 bytes, each byte in Hexa representation, the byte order is little-endian.

so my input is:

```
;comment
MAIN: add       #3, #5,     #9
LOOP: ori        #9, -5, #2
      la    val1
      jmp   Next
Next: move  #20, #4
      bgt   #0, #2, END
      la    K
      sw    #0, 4, #10
      bne   #31, #9     , LOOP
      call  val1
      jmp   #4
END:  stop 
STR:  .asciz    "aBcd"
LIST: .db   6, -9
      .dh   27056
      .dw   5
.entry K   
K:     .dw 31,-12
.extern     val1
```

**[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnrYL.png)**
(the first line is the above example's Hexadecimal representation).

but when I try to output each byte like so:

```
r_instruction inst;
inst.r.opcode = 0;
inst.r.rs = 3;
inst.r.rt = 5;
inst.r.rd = 9;
inst.r.funct = 1;
inst.r.unused = 0;
printf("%x %x %x %x", inst.bytes.first, 
    inst.bytes.second, 
    inst.bytes.third, inst.bytes.fourth);
>> c0 28 29 0
```

my main problem is how to convert my existing instruction to the requested presentation

Comment: Please show your attempt at the problem, including input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: The C standard leaves the order in which bit-fields are put into storage units implementation-defined and leaves unspecified certain other things that affect how bit-fields appear in memory. Unless you want to bind yourself to a specific compiler and documentation for that compiler guaranteeing the bit-field behavior you want, it is better to assemble the bits yourself by using the left-shift operator `<<` to move them to the desired position and the bitwise OR `|` to merge them with other fields.

Comment: when I changed the order of the bitfields in the struct, I managed to put the bits in the desired order, but u described the order of the bits as implementation-defined, so how much does it really change from compiler to compiler, and will it matter if I'm only using GCC?

Comment: @bestman Even if you stick with a specific compiler, platform and arch, a new version of that compiler (or other software changes in the environment) could still break your code. For instance, in my answer I gave you an implementation-independent way to generate the output, regardless of the order of `struct`'s members and without using bitfields.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `packed` `struct`s with bitfields, consider using normal `struct`s and do the generation of the raw instruction yourself. For instance, let's take an instruction of type "J":

```c
typedef struct { uint32_t addr; uint32_t opcode; uint32_t isReg; } j_instr;

// this function generates a 32-bit raw instruction (that you can then convert to ASCII hexadecimal or whatever you want)
uint32_t gen_j_instr(j_instr instr) {
  uint32_t result = 0;

  // let's add the opcode
  result += instr.opcode << 26; // 26 is the starting position of opcode

  // let's add the isReg
  result += instr.isReg << 25; // 25 is the starting position of isReg

  // let's add the addr
  result += instr.addr; // no shift needed, addr is at position 0

  return result;
}
```

The C11 standard gives implementations a lot of freedom when using `struct`s with bitfields, therefore you can make few assumptions about their exact binary representation. On the other hand, using the previous method, you're completely independent of how your `struct` will be represented in binary.

Answer (score 0):

put them in a union, together with a plain unsigned int;

---

```
typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__))
{
    unsigned opcode : 6;
    unsigned rs : 5;
    unsigned rt : 5;
    unsigned rd : 5;
    unsigned funct : 5;
    unsigned : 6;
} r_instruction;

typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__))
{
    unsigned rs : 5;
    unsigned rt : 5;
    unsigned opcode : 6;
    unsigned immed : 16;
} i_instruction;

typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__))
{
    unsigned addr : 25;
    unsigned opcode : 6;
    unsigned isReg : 1;
} j_instruction;

union all_meuk {
        r_instruction r_meuk;
        i_instruction i_meuk;
        j_instruction j_meuk;
        unsigned all;
        };
```

Comment: Does this put the bits in the order OP wants them? How do you know?

Comment: I don't know. I think the OP should handle the endianness himself, he knows better than I do. Also: there are two endianesses: one for the host platform, and one for the target.

Comment: The order of bit-fields in storage units is a separate issue from endianness.

Comment: That as well is something the OP should know and I cannot know.

Comment: The point is the code in this answer does not provide an answer if it does not ensure the bits are in the right places. It is essentially not a right answer.

Comment: Maybe we are over-estimating the OP's level of insight. (personally, I would never use __packed__ or rely on the ordering of bitfields) I just intended to show the OP the union solution, which he seems to have adapted.